# How to enter large matrix into relational database(DB) mysql

Tags: mysql, database, matrix, phpmyadmin, relational-database

I have 500 x 500 matrix which needs to be retrieve and update for every single recommendation. I am looking for best way to do that because current time required is almost around 30 sec.

instead of update operation (which was taking a long time) I tried delete those rows then insert for given user which reduce time to certain extent.

Is it possible to add whole row of matrix which 500 number list as one row of mysql table?

```
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
cur.execute("select rowno from matrixinput where username = %s", (usercur, ))
if cur.fetchone():
    for i in range(0, 500):
        cur.execute("delete from matrixinput where username=%s and rowno=%s ", (usercur, i))


for i in range(0, 500):
    for j in range(0, 500):
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO matrixinput(username, rowno, colno, Qmatrix, Rmatrix) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (usercur, i, j, myMusic.Q[i][j], myMusic.R[i][j]))
```

mysql.connection.commit()
cur.close()

For example if we have 2D list as [[0,0,0] [1,1,1][2,2,2]]
Can we enter whole row [0,0,0] in one row of database.
But since for this case there are not 3 elements but 500 in list as 2d list has 500× 500 dimension. Is it possible to add all 500 element row of list in one row of db table

Comment: Can you add some example code or structuring?

Comment: @ThiagoValente sure

Comment: "500 x 500 matrix" with one row in `matrixinput` for each cell means you're inserting or updating a quarter of a million table rows each time. What kind of hardware and operating system is this on? If it's a PC, 30 seconds seems reasonable.

Comment: Do all quarter of a million cell values change at each update? Might be better to issue an `UPDATE` statement only for the specific `username, rowno, colno` that have changed.

Comment: BTW why are you deleting `rowno` by agonising `rowno`? Don't you just mean: delete everything for this `username`? `"delete from matrixinput where username = %s", (usercur)`

Comment: "instead of update operation (which was taking a long time) " but that _wasn't_ an update operation: it was a quarter of a million `update` statements, each via a separate call to `cur.execute`. So that's a quarter of a million function calls, a quarter of a million parses of an `update` statement, a quarter of a million x 5 decodes of `%s` arguments. 30 seconds seems excellent performance.

Comment: Yes most of million cell updates so selective update is not possible. This 30 sec are actually for base case. When user data increases the performance reduce. This time is when system has only one user. For multiuser time increase. Is there any other way yo save matrix in db instead of saving each value in each row. @AntC